# "My code is not working"

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run the below code. But it is showing the error of Subscript out of range. When I tried to debug it, it is showing error in the 5 line: Range(“A1”).Select
While debugging, when I made the Sheet1 of 4th line as Sheet2, then it is not going on Sheet2.
Please help me run the code properly.

```
Sub excelmacro()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets(“Sheet1”).Select
Range(“A1”).Select

Sheets(“Sheet2”).Select
Range(“A2”).Select

For i = 1 To 3
Sheets(“Sheet1”).Select
If Len(ActiveCell.Value) > 1 Then

Sheets(“Sheet1”).Select
Xname = Right(ActiveCell.Value, Len(ActiveCell.Value) - 6)
Xdesig = Right(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value, Len(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value) - 13)
Xsalary = Right(ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Value, Len(ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Value) - 8)


Sheets(“Sheet2”).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Xname
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Xdesig
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Xsalary
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Sheets(“Sheet1”).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Select

Else
i = 10
End If
i = i - 1
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I think your problem is the quotation marks you are using. It looks like they are from a word document or some other rich text format editor. Use a plain text editor, like Notepad,  to replace all the quotes with standard ones. Also you should avoid selecting sheets and cells and just reference them directly. I can expound upon that issue further if you'd like once you check the quotation situation.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. The mistake was of Quotation marks only.

Comment: But now I am getting the error of "Application-defined or object-defined error in line "For i = 1 to 3"

Comment: You probably have `Option Explicit` turned on, which is good, so you will have to explicitly define your variables before you use them. I would declare your variables on the second line, starting with `Dim i as double, Xname as string, ...` and so on. I am assuming the rest of your variables are strings

Comment: Can you please type it and show it to me as I am getting Syntax error

Comment: Your For loop needs an explicit "Next i" at the end of the loop.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're looping - if the text length of the active cell is not greater than 1 then  you set i to 10 and I guess the loop ends - as i is now greater than 3, otherwise you remove 1 from i and the code may end up getting stuck in an endless loop.  Is the loop just trying to loop through all rows in column A that has a value?

Answer (score 0):

The quotation marks are oddball and create an error, but even after changing to 'normal' quoates there is a Subscript out of range error:

Instead of using `Sheets`, try `Worksheets`:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
```

Comment: It is working fine with the quotes thing. But now I am getting the error of "Application-defined or object-defined error in line "For i = 1 to 3"

Answer (score 0):

To summarize my comments:

The double-quotes in the original code are oddly formatted. Use Notepad or the VBA IDE to replace them with appropriate plain text double quotes.

Be sure to declare your variables before using them if `Option Explicit` is turned on. Also just a good practice to follow even if it were not on.

(To be updated when I have more time this evening) Avoid making selections and using`ActiveCell`/`ActiveSheet` references.

With minor changes to your code it should look like this:

```
Sub excelmacro()
Dim i As Double, _
    Xname As String, _
    Xdesig As String, _
    Xsalary As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1").Select

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A2").Select

For i = 1 To 3
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
If Len(ActiveCell.Value) > 1 Then

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Xname = Right(ActiveCell.Value, Len(ActiveCell.Value) - 6)
Xdesig = Right(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value, Len(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value) - 13)
Xsalary = Right(ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Value, Len(ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Value) - 8)


Sheets("Sheet2").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Xname
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Xdesig
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Xsalary
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Select

Else
i = 10
End If
i = i - 1
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but what is the "_" after the "Double," and after "Xname as String,"

Comment: I am still getting the same error of "Application-defined or Object-defined error" after running your code. ! :(

Comment: There is a small typo in the `Dim` statement.  `xsalar` should be `xsalary`.  @Komal Fix that and it should work.

Comment: The underscores are to break the line without breaking actually starting a new line. If you were to actually hit return after each declaration and start a new line you would have to do `Dim ... as ...` for each variable. Putting an underscore at the end of a line lets you continue your code on the next line. It's mostly a style/readability preference. Good spot @Scott Craner, I will fix the typo.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
Sub excelmacro()

    Dim lastrowinSheet1 As Long
    Dim cellinSheet2 As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim x As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        'Set a reference to cell A1 on Sheet2.
        Set cellinSheet2 = .Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

        With .Worksheets("Sheet1")
            'This will return the last row number containing data in column A.
            lastrowinSheet1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            'Now loop through each cell in column A of sheet1.
            For x = 1 To lastrowinSheet1
                If Len(.Cells(x, 1)) > 1 Then
                    cellinSheet2.Value = Right(.Cells(x, 1).Value, Len(.Cells(x, 1).Value) - 6)
                    cellinSheet2.Offset(, 1) = Right(.Cells(x, 1).Offset(1).Value, Len(.Cells(x, 1).Offset(1).Value) - 13)
                    cellinSheet2.Offset(, 2) = Right(.Cells(x, 1).Offset(2).Value, Len(.Cells(x, 1).Offset(2).Value) - 8)
                    Set cellinSheet2 = cellinSheet2.Offset(1)
                    x = x + 2
                End If
            Next x

        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

I tried taking apart your code - I think this is what it's doing:

```
Sub excelmacro1()

    'Stop the screen flicker.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Select cell A1 on Sheet1.
    Sheets(“Sheet1”).Select
    Range(“A1”).Select

    'Select cell A2 on sheet 2.
    Sheets(“Sheet2”).Select
    Range(“A2”).Select

    For i = 1 To 3

        'Select Sheet1 again.
        Sheets(“Sheet1”).Select

        'If the length of text in the ActiveCell is greater than 1 character then
        'execute the lines up to ELSE.
        If Len(ActiveCell.Value) > 1 Then

            'Select Sheet1 yet again.
            Sheets(“Sheet1”).Select

            'Hope the value in the ActiveCell isn't longer than 6 digits, or it will error out.
            'Take all characters from the ActiveCell except the last 6.
            Xname = Right(ActiveCell.Value, Len(ActiveCell.Value) - 6)
            'Take all characters from the ActiveCell except the last 13.
            Xdesig = Right(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value, Len(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value) - 13)
            'Take all characters from the ActiveCell except the last 8.
            Xsalary = Right(ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Value, Len(ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Value) - 8)

            'Select Sheet2.
            Sheets(“Sheet2”).Select
            'Place the values in ActiveCell and the two columns to the right.
            ActiveCell.Value = Xname
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Xdesig
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Xsalary
            'Select the next row down.
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            'Active Sheet1 again.
            Sheets(“Sheet1”).Select
            'Select the cell 3 rows down from the previous row.
            ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Select
        Else
        'If the lengh of text in the ActiveCell is 1 character or less then set the value of i to 10.
        i = 10
        End If
        'Remove 1 from i.
        i = i - 1
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```